# How to reconcile Visual Studio comment expectations with code having Doxygen comments?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, comments, tooltip, doxygen

It is normal for code that was written for Doxygen processing to have lines like this.

```
int myVariable; ///< description of myVariable
```

However, when Visual Studio (e.g. VS 2015) is working with code prepared with these Doxygen comments, its tooltip information for `myVariable` will show

`XML comment contains invalid XML: Whitespace is not allowed at this location.`

The problem appears to be the presence of "<" immediately following "///".  That appears to be interpreted by Visual Studio as signalling (improperly formatted) XML content.  However, this combination is present with the "<" to signal to Doxygen that the comment applies to the preceding item on the line, not to a following item.

Assume that we are talking about an existing body of code that already follows this Doxygen convention.  It is already written this way in many places.

Is there a way to adjust or teach or set Visual Studio so that it will treat such comments as normal documenting comments for the preceding item such that they will appear in the tooltips for these items?

Comment: Same problem in VS2017RC4...

Comment: Would a solution be to replace the `///<` by `//!<` comments? Will be a bit of work though.

Comment: @albert Thank you for that suggestion!  Please add it as a proposed answer/solution.  Technically, it isn't the simple solution I was hoping for by just adjusting Visual Studio.  However, since no one has suggested any such answer, your observation deserves recognition as an alternate work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doxygen has different comment styles (see manual the section about "special comment blocks", in this case the paragraph about "Putting documentation after members".
Here we see the possibilities:

```
int var; /**< Detailed description after the member */
or
int var; //!< Detailed description after the member
//!<
or
int var; ///< Detailed description after the member
```

In this case we can switch from `///<` to `//!<`

Comment: Even though in my question I was hoping for an easy way to adjust Visual Studio itself to resolve the issue, no such solution has ever been suggested by anyone.  That being the case, this alternate work around is the most helpful suggestion that has been made.  Thankfully, one can use Visual Studio's Replace in Files to replace many cases of ///< with //!< as a single operation.  So that is not very hard to do.

Comment: However this is not intelligent at all especially after another 3 years. By "//!<" it shows everything with "!<" at the beginning then

Comment: @ripfreeworld please explain what you mean with your comment, what you tested and the doxygen version used.

Comment: @albert I have the version 1.9.1 for Doxygen and I mean using `//!<` in Visual Studio (2019) is not perfect because the `!<` will stay at the beginning of tooltip information.

Comment: @ripfreeworld You now mention VS(2019) what is the relation here? Maybe you should open a new question with a complete example and what you see.

Comment: @albert The question is just duplicate. Exactly the same with this one. I just comment your answer. Switching from `///<` to `//!<` brings `!<` into the tooltip information. Why should I open a new question for this?

Comment: The purpose of "comment" here is to say that Doxygen or Visual Studio did nothing regarding this issue in these years. Neither `///<` nor `//!<` is a perfect solution for VS user. And I'm not blaming your answer, it's a good compromise solution

Comment: @ripfreeworld I just try to see where the problem lies is it in doxygen or is it in VS 2019. When I use doxygen and look at the tooltip on the source page of the file where the `var`s are defined I don't see any `!<` in the tooltips (neither with 1.9.1 nor with the current 1.9.3).

Comment: @albert Sorry for the missunderstanding. I thought you all have this issue. So I put my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70673758/tooltip-shows-comments-of-member-variables-with-fronting-while-using-doxyge) with screenshot.